# Update "How To Ask" box to deter requests for specific legal advice

Tags: discussion, feature-request, legal-advice, disclaimer

As stated on the side of the main menu of the [law.stackoverflow.com](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions) site:

> Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

This seems to deter some, but not all from asking personalized questions about a legal matter they've found themselves in.

Would a simpler clause of the statement used on the home page be effective in the "How To Ask" box?

Comment: Related: [Another proposal to update "How to ask" box](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/673/10).